# Address into Coordinates

Tags: ios, swift

I am using following code, which fails and does not enter inside function.

```
geocoder.geocodeAddressString(location, completionHandler: {(placemarks: [CLPlacemark]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in //Fails here

        let placemark = placemarks?.first
        let lat = placemark?.location?.coordinate.latitude
        let lon = placemark?.location?.coordinate.longitude
        print("Lat: \(lat), Lon: \(lon)")
    } as! CLGeocodeCompletionHandler )
```

Please help!
Thanks in advance :-)

Comment: what error you are getting?

Comment: you can get coordinates by requesting here https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=\(addresString)

Comment: BTW in `Swift 3` `NSError?` will be `Error?`

Comment: @Rahul Exc_BREAKPOINT  on  } as! CLGeocodeCompletionHandler ) and I tried with Error in place of NSError

Comment: @Spurti Please make sure to include the error message you're getting.

Comment: Please press ⇧⌘0 (zero), type or paste `CLGeocodeCompletionHandler`, select Swift if necessary and press return. There you can find the proper syntax of the closure.

Comment: @thedp BREAKPOINT on } as! CLGeocodeCompletionHandler )

Comment: @vadian I checked Its same syntax

Comment: No, it is not. See my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the wrong syntax, there are no parameter labels in Swift 3 and `NSError` has been replaced with `Error`:

```
geocoder.geocodeAddressString(location) { (placemarks, error) in 

    if let placemark = placemarks?.first, let location = placemark.location {
       let lat = location.coordinate.latitude
       let lon = location.coordinate.longitude
       print("Lat: \(lat), Lon: \(lon)")
    }
}
```